# Client - Server socket programming with python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, client-server, communication

Below are my three scripts. I need to send the message from sricpt 1(Sensor.py) to script 2.(Client.py). And then the script 2 should send the message to script 3(Server.py).
It works fine till script 2 but the message isn't being received at the script 3 and the recvfrom() keeps waiting. There is no error but the script 3 doesn't show the message. Im using UDP. Please help.

SCRIPT 1(Sensor.py)

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime

CLIENT_IP = '192.168.1.109'
PORT = 23567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (CLIENT_IP, PORT)

udpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    sendData = input("> ")
    if sendData is None:
        break
    udpCliSock.sendto(sendData.encode(), ADDR)

udpCliSock.close()
```

SCRIPT 2(Client.py)

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime

HOST = '192.168.1.103'
CLIENT_IP='192.168.1.109'
PORT = 5005
SENSOR_PORT_NO=23567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
CLIENT_ADDR=(CLIENT_IP,SENSOR_PORT_NO)

udpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client.bind(CLIENT_ADDR)
while True:

    print("...waiting for response...")
    #recv_data, ADDR = udpCliSock.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
    recv_data, ADDR = client.recvfrom(1024)
    if recv_data is not None:
        recv_data = recv_data.decode()
        print("[%s]: receiving data from server %s:%s  :%s" % (ctime(),ADDR[0], ADDR[1], recv_data))

    sendData = recv_data
    udpCliSock.sendto(sendData.encode(), ADDR)

udpCliSock.close()
```

SCRIPT 3(Server.py)

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime

HOST = '192.168.1.103'
PORT = 5005
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

udpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
udpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
while True:
    print("...waiting for message...")
    data, ADDR = udpSerSock.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
    print(data.decode)
    if data is None:
        break
    print("[%s]: From Address %s:%s receive data: %s" % (ctime(),ADDR[0],ADDR[1], data.decode()))

udpSerSock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in the Client.py, you are overwriting the address of the server when you receive the datagram from the sensor. Here:

```
recv_data, ADDR = client.recvfrom(1024)
```

`ADDR` starts out with the server's socket address, but this function overwrites that variable with the sensor's socket address. So when you try to send, you're sending it back to the sensor (who of course isn't ever receiving it).

A better method is to `connect` that socket to the server at the beginning. Then you can just use `send` instead of `sendto` since the address won't be changing. Should work after that:

```
...
udpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
udpCliSock.connect(ADDR)                # <<<<<<===============
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client.bind(CLIENT_ADDR)
while True:
    print("...waiting for response...")
    recv_data, addr = client.recvfrom(1024)
    if recv_data is not None:
        recv_data = recv_data.decode()
        print("[%s]: receiving data from server %s:%s  :%s" % (ctime(),addr[0], addr[1], recv_data))
    sendData = recv_data
    udpCliSock.send(sendData.encode())  # <<<<<<===============
udpCliSock.close()
```